# how to add Mac OS Framework on Cmake file for C++ project

Tags: c++, cmake, sdk, frameworks, vulkan

I am trying to add an external library (Vulkan) to my project. This library is pre-compiled and has a framework.

My project tree:

```
- build
- source
  - Entry
     - main.cpp
- include
- ext
  - vulkan
      - macos
         - include
         - lib
         - Frameworks
- CMakeLists.txt
```

In my CMakeLists.txt, I try to add the lib of my vulkan lib like this:

```
if(APPLE)
  set(vulkan_lib_dir ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/ext/vulkan/macos/lib)
    file(GLOB LIB_VULKAN ${vulkan_lib_dir}/*.dylib )
  INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/ext/vulkan/macos/include)
endif()
```

and then

```
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(my_exe  ${LIB_VULKAN})
```

When I use `cmake ..` and then `make` on my build directory, it works perfectly but when I run my executable `./my_exe`

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /tmp/macos-sdk-build/shaderc/src/build/libshaderc/libshaderc_shared.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/benz/Documents/Dev/build/my_exe/source/Entry/./my_exe
  Reason: image not found
```

I think I have to set the framework in my CMake too, but I did not find a solution that made `my_exe` work.

EDIT : this is the output of otool -L of my executable

```
./S2Engine:
    @rpath/libMoltenVK.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    @rpath/libVkLayer_api_dump.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    @rpath/libVkLayer_core_validation.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    @rpath/libVkLayer_khronos_validation.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    @rpath/libVkLayer_object_lifetimes.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    @rpath/libVkLayer_stateless_validation.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    @rpath/libVkLayer_thread_safety.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    @rpath/libVkLayer_unique_objects.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /tmp/macos-sdk-build/shaderc/src/build/libshaderc/libshaderc_shared.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    @rpath/libvulkan.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.1.121)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Cocoa.framework/Versions/A/Cocoa (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 22.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 275.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation (compatibility version 150.0.0, current version 1350.10.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/Versions/A/CoreVideo (compatibility version 1.2.0, current version 1.5.0)
    /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 307.5.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1238.60.2)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit (compatibility version 45.0.0, current version 1504.84.100)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Versions/A/CoreGraphics (compatibility version 64.0.0, current version 1070.22.1)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/CoreServices (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 775.20.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation (compatibility version 300.0.0, current version 1349.93.0)
    /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 228.0.0)
```

this is the output of otool -L of libvulkan.dylib

```
libvulkan.dylib:
    @rpath/libvulkan.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.1.121)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1252.200.5)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation (compatibility version 150.0.0, current version 1560.12.0)
```

```
[100%] Linking CXX executable S2Engine
cd /Users/benz/Documents/S2EngineDEV/build/S2Engine/source/Entry && /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.11.3/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/S2Engine.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++  -g -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names  CMakeFiles/S2Engine.dir/main.cpp.o CMakeFiles/S2Engine.dir/__/Manager/EnvironmentManager.cpp.o CMakeFiles/S2Engine.dir/__/Manager/LoggerManager.cpp.o CMakeFiles/S2Engine.dir/__/Manager/MemoryManager.cpp.o CMakeFiles/S2Engine.dir/__/Manager/WindowManager.cpp.o CMakeFiles/S2Engine.dir/__/Logger/Logger.cpp.o CMakeFiles/S2Engine.dir/__/Logger/FileLog.cpp.o CMakeFiles/S2Engine.dir/__/Memory/Memory.cpp.o CMakeFiles/S2Engine.dir/__/Memory/StackAllocator.cpp.o CMakeFiles/S2Engine.dir/__/Window/Window.cpp.o CMakeFiles/S2Engine.dir/__/Window/PatternWindow.cpp.o CMakeFiles/S2Engine.dir/__/Window/PatternGLFW3_VULKAN.cpp.o  -o S2Engine -Wl,-rpath,/Users/benz/Documents/S2EngineDEV/ext/vulkan/macos/lib ../../../ext/glfw33/src/libglfw3.a ../../../../ext/vulkan/macos/lib/libMoltenVK.dylib ../../../../ext/vulkan/macos/lib/libSPIRV-Tools-shared.dylib ../../../../ext/vulkan/macos/lib/libVkLayer_api_dump.dylib ../../../../ext/vulkan/macos/lib/libVkLayer_core_validation.dylib ../../../../ext/vulkan/macos/lib/libVkLayer_khronos_validation.dylib ../../../../ext/vulkan/macos/lib/libVkLayer_object_lifetimes.dylib ../../../../ext/vulkan/macos/lib/libVkLayer_stateless_validation.dylib ../../../../ext/vulkan/macos/lib/libVkLayer_thread_safety.dylib ../../../../ext/vulkan/macos/lib/libVkLayer_unique_objects.dylib ../../../../ext/vulkan/macos/lib/libshaderc_shared.1.dylib ../../../../ext/vulkan/macos/lib/libshaderc_shared.dylib ../../../../ext/vulkan/macos/lib/libvulkan.1.1.121.dylib ../../../../ext/vulkan/macos/lib/libvulkan.1.dylib ../../../../ext/vulkan/macos/lib/libvulkan.dylib -framework Cocoa -framework IOKit -framework CoreFoundation -framework CoreVideo 
[100%] Built target S2Engine
/usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.11.3/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /Users/benz/Documents/S2EngineDEV/build/CMakeFiles 0
```

Comment: Show the output of `otool -L` on both your executable and on `libvulkan.dylib`.

Comment: I have edited my post with the output..

Comment: So the question is what is linking in that `/tmp/macos-sdk-build/shaderc/src/build/libshaderc/libshaderc_shared.1.dylib` library?

Comment: I do not know, it's the first time I have this kind of problem when linkind shared library. There is nothing is folder /tmp/macos-sdk-build/

Comment: Your question isn't about cmake as that appears to be working fine.  You need to show the linker line to see if that shows any signs of that library.  However it's strange that it links at all if that file is missing during build.  However I know you should not be linking all those `libVkLayer` libraries and just link `libvulkan.dylib`.

Comment: How can I show the linker line ?

Comment: `make clean all VERBOSE=1`

Comment: I have edited my post with the output of the linking part . Doest it help ?

Answer (score 1):

You are linking in `../../../../ext/vulkan/macos/lib/libshaderc_shared.dylib` and if you ran `otool -L` on it you would no doubt see that it thinks it's called `/tmp/.../libshaderc_shared.dylib` which is the root-cause of your issue (it basically tells the runtime linker where to fetch that library from).

That file is broken and you can only fix it by running `install_name_tool` on it to rename it to use `@rpath` like the other libraries.

But you don't need to be linking against all those libraries so simply change the `CMakeLists.txt` file to only link against `libvulkan.dylib`:

```
if(APPLE)
  set(LIB_VULKAN ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/ext/vulkan/macos/lib/libvulkan.dylib)
  INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/ext/vulkan/macos/include)
endif()
```